# Analytic expression for a universe without a big bang

Tags: cosmology, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, cosmological-constant

I was reading introduction to modern cosmology by Andrew Liddle. On page 56 he shows a graph of the $\Omega_{\Lambda}$, $\Omega_{0}$ plane and there's a region where no big bang is needed, later on the text he says that there's an analytic expression for that curve but it was too complicated to give. I looked for it in the Suzuki's paper from which the graph was taken and some other bibliography but didn't find anything, does anyone know where I can find the expression?

[image: Graph from Introduction tomoderncosmology]

Comment: As seen in [this graph](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Parameter-space-OM-OL-The-green-dashed-line-OL-1-OM-corresponds-to-a-flat_fig22_1805222) from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1805222_Cosmology_and_Astrophysics) this appears to be a family of curves, of which only the $\infty$ case is shown above.